# uploading Image texture creating moire

Tags: fine-uploader

We have implemented FineUploader and are running into an issue with some images that our clients are uploading.  For large image files with a repeated canvas texture, FineUploader resizes the images fine, but a moiré is introduced into the final image.  Is there any way to help prevent this from happening?

Here is an example: 
http://205.238.27.187/Hagan/site/Artwork-Detail.cfm?ArtistsID=1110&NewID=10709

Comment: do you have an original image to compare this to?

Comment: Sorry here is a link to the original image that was uploaded: http://www.managedartwork.com/Images/afternoonSail-original.jpg

And here is a link to the resized image that FineUploader created: http://www.artworkmanagerdemo.com/Artwork-Detail.cfm?ArtistsID=1044&NewID=10194

Answer (score 1):

This is not because of the quality setting.

Most browsers use linear interpolation rather than bicubic when resizing images.
Fine Uploader uses the default browser image resizing algorithm.

The solution I've found is [limby-resize](https://github.com/danschumann/limby-resize). It uses pixel averaging/a much better resizing algo but is more CPU intensive. There is a link to a demo in the readme file. (Fine Uploader uses the "Crappy" method)

In megapix-image.js around  [line #168](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/blob/050e94d975388512835f3b96856ea209aa9c3fc9/client/js/image-support/megapix-image.js#L168) or in the fine uploader source code,

Replace:

```
else {
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
}

canvas.qqImageRendered && canvas.qqImageRendered();
```

With:

```
else {
    var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    tmpCanvas.width = iw;
    tmpCanvas.height = ih;
    var tmpCtx = tmpCanvas.getContext("2d");
    tmpCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    canvasResize(tmpCanvas, canvas, function () {
        alert("Image resized by limby-resize");
        canvas.qqImageRendered && canvas.qqImageRendered();
    });
}
```

And include limby-resize's canvas_resize.js before the fine uploader js file in your HTML.

Comment: This is a great find! I've opened up a case in the Fine Uploader issue tracker to explore integration, either directly or document how users can easily replace the image manipulation algorithm in Fine Uploader with limby-resize. https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1524

Comment: Fine Uploader 5.10, to be released on 16 June 2016, will include a new feature that will allow you to easily delegate to the image resize library of your choice.